# $O$ is the center of a circle with $AB$ diameter. If $OD$ is perpendicular to $AB$ and meets chord $AC$ , then prove that circle $AOD = O,B,D,C$.

Tags: geometry, circles

> $O$ is the center of a circle with $AB$ diameter. If $OD$ is perpendicular to $AB$ and meets chord $AC$ or $AC$ produced at $D$, then prove that circle $AOD$ is equal to the circle through $O,B,D,C$.

The triangles $AOD$ and $ACB$ are similar. I've tried using similarity for the above theorem but we need to show that the two radiuses are equal. Since, $AOD$ is a right-angled triangle, its circumcenter lies on the hypotenuse.

I am not able to proceed further. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: DA (the diameter of circle OAD) is symmetrically equal to DB( the diameter of circle ODB).

Comment: You should ponder to add a diagram to this kind of questions, otherwise it may be hard to follow .

Comment: @Mick Thanks! $$$$